# ¿Cómo puedo usar $sum para sumar el total?

Tags: mongodb

Tengo [este esquema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qJ9I.png):

```javascript
{
    activo:
        [{
            description_act: {
                type: String
            },
            debe_act: {
                type: Number
            },
            haber_act: {
                type: Number
            },
            total_act: {
                type: Number,
                default: 0
            }
        }],
```

Me gustaría sacar el total de `total_act` pero no lo consigo. Hice [estas pruebas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyApz.png) pero no me da el resultado:

```javascript
db.balance_apertura_schemas.aggregate(
    [
    {$group:
    {_id: null,
    total:{ $sum:{
        activo:
            "$total_act"

        },
        }
    }
    }
    ]).pretty();
```

Esta es la salida que obtengo:

```
{ 
    "_id" : null, 
    "total" : 0 
}
```

¿Cómo puedo usar $sum para sumar el total?

Answer (score 0):

Encontre una solución usando `$unwind`, que es como convertir el array en objetos, y [me quedo así](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6ALo.png) al final:

```javascript
db.balance_apertura_schemas.aggregate(
    [
    {$unwind: "$activo"},
    {$group:
    {_id: null,
    total:{ $sum: "$activo.total_act"}
    }
    }
    ]).pretty();
```

Comment: El código va _como texto, con formato_. Además, explica brevemente su funcionamiento: lee [answer] y pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu respuesta.